# JTree not showing anything

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm trying to draw a `JTree`.

Nothing seems wrong but this doesn't show anything. Did I do something wrong?

Or is it that I made mistake on somewhere else with the GUI?

```
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String1);

        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String2);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String3);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String4);

        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String5);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String6);
        root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(String7);

        tree = new JTree();
        model = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
        tree.setModel(model);
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(10);

        display = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        add(new JScrollPane(tree));
        add(new JScrollPane(display));
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the tree.

Comment: Just noticed the [edit]. When can we expect to see an edit with an MRE / SSCCE?

Comment: I'm very sorry but do you mean I should put all of my codes (from import line ~ main method)? I just googled about MRE / SSCCE. I'm not sure I understand the article about MRE / SSCCE correctly.

Comment: In order for us to help you effectively, we need to screengrab the code you post in your question, run it in our Eclipse IDE, and recommend changes.  Most of us can't just look at code and see problems.  We need to execute the code.  That's what a [mre] does for you and for us.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! 
Executable code. Got it!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *"Most of us can't just look at code and see problems. We need to execute the code."* Well said. Some (rare) people enjoy visually inspecting code snippets. OTOH I'll only look closely at code once it's compiled in my IDE, formatted and colored the way I expect.

Comment: The tree looks fine. The problem is likely to be elsewhere, yet another reason for MRE/SSCCE. My guess  is that if you changed `add(new JScrollPane(tree));` with `add(new JLable("Test"));` it wouldn't show either. If that is the case it well demonstrates the benefit of preparing MRE/SSCCE as a *debuging* tool.